# Update data in simple dialog Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to update `ListView` in dialog when called function `_issueItem()` ?. Nothing is happened when I press button issue item, `ListView` is not updating. `ListView` is in StatefulBuilder but it doesn't work. Please help. I am calling `setState` when `issue item button` is pressed and I call `setState` when I want to update `ListView`, but nothing works.

***My ListView code***

```
StatefulBuilder createIssuedItemsList(List<IssuedItems>? issuedItems) {
 return StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (context, setState) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: issuedItems!.length,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return const Divider();
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        IssuedItems _issuedItems = issuedItems[index];
        Uint8List _bytes =
            const Base64Decoder().convert(_issuedItems.photo.toString());
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => {log(_issuedItems.item)},
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(_issuedItems.item +
                ',  ' +
                _issuedItems.count +
                ' ' +
                _issuedItems.countOption +
                ',  ' +
                _issuedItems.date),
            leading: Container(
                height: 7.h,
                width: 7.w,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: Image.memory(_bytes).image))),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);}
```

***Issuing items***

```
Response response =
    await ServerSideApi.create(UserState.getIP()!, 1).issueItem(data);

switch (response.body) {
  case 'not_enough_items':
    _showToast(4);
    break;
  case 'count_option_error':
    _showToast(5);
    break;
  case 'item_already_issued':
    _showToast(6);
    break;
  case 'item_issued_successfully':
    _showToast(7);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    setState(() {
      getIssuedItems(brigadeNumber);
    });
    break;
}
```

***Function to attach issued items from server***

```
FutureBuilder<Response<List<IssuedItems>>> getIssuedItems(String brigadeNumber) {
   var data = {'brigade': brigadeNumber};

return FutureBuilder<Response<List<IssuedItems>>>(
  future: ServerSideApi.create(UserState.getIP()!, 6).getIssuedItems(data),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    while (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
        snapshot.hasData) {
      var issuedItems = snapshot.data!.body;
      log(issuedItems.toString());
      return createIssuedItemsList(issuedItems);
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('Нет выданных товаров'),
      );
    }
  },
);}
```

***Issue Item Button***

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
                label: const Text('Выдать'),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                      _issueItem(brigade.brigadeNumber, _itemIndex!,
                          dropDownItemName!, listOfTextEditingController);
                    }))
```

Comment: Please add all the widget code, you have it in pieces and it's not very clear where the problem might be. Also  `var issuedItems = snapshot.data!.body;` It seems to me that nothing will come to you here Have you watched this part?

Comment: Data is coming from server, but ListView is not updating

Comment: What is the link to the server?

Comment: @АлександрИнженер I am using OpenServer panel, server link is my pc's ip address, I have added IssueItem button code, all void methods are in state class